# Unnest arrays of different dimensions

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unnest, set-returning-functions

Is there a function or query that could return arrays of different dimensions as a set? For example, I would like to return the values

```
ARRAY[1]
ARRAY[2,3]
ARRAY[4,5,6]
```

as

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`unnest()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE):

```
SELECT unnest(arr) AS elem
FROM (
 VALUES
   (ARRAY[1])
  ,(ARRAY[2,3])
  ,(ARRAY[4,5,6])
  ) t (arr);
```

Returns as requested.
More details:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Comment: Note that the order of the results isn't guaranteed, though in practice it's consistent. You'll need 9.4's `WITH ORDINALITY` to guarantee it.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I added a link to elaborate on that.

Answer (score 0):

try the following query

```
select unnest(a) from
(select array[1] as arr union select array[2,3]
union select array[4,5,6]) t
```

hopes this may be helpful :) ..